# wrap inline li's into equal rows

Tags: html, css

I have a variable number of LI's that are displayed inline across the page (in a navigation menu) with CSS like this:

```
 ul.nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
 }

 ul.nav li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

When the page is made narrower, the navigation menu is wrapping as it should, however, I'd like to try and equal the number of items on each row.

For example when 9 items appear, and the page only fits 8, i'd like to have 5 in the top row and 4 wrap below, rather then 8 in the top row and on lonely li move to the next row. The problem is that they have to be center aligned in this template, so it looks pretty bad with one row full and the second row with a single item.

It doesn't have to be exact, so some kind of margin solution that might force down a few (6 and 3 would be better then 8 and 1) would work. Does anyone have an idea how I might do this?

Cheers!

**Update:** So apparently I didn't explain myself very well. I'm trying to balance rows, not ensure a certain number at a give width.

lets take an example... Lets say I have room for 4 times (we'll say the lis are fixed with 100px in a 400px space)

```
| -----  -----  -----  ----- |
||     ||     ||     ||     ||
| -----  -----  -----  ----- |
```

Now when I have 5 items, instead of 4 and 1, I want this

```
|    -----  -----  -----     |
|   |     ||     ||     |    |
|    -----  -----  -----     |
|        -----  -----        |
|       |     ||     |       |
|        -----  -----        |
```

for 6 items, 3 and 3
for 7 items, 4 and 3
for 8 items, 4 and 4
for 9 items, 3 3 and 3

Can Right now I'm starting to thing I need to do this programatically in PHP, but that doesn't address people resizing the window

Answer (score 0):

if your div size is fix so please give a fix width a particular li. 
for example
suppose you have a div like 500px now we want 4 item in the top and 1 below. so li width will be 110px approx.

so please try to fix your li width.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the first 5 inside another `div` having `display:inline-block` and the rest of them inside another `div` having `display:inline-block` that should break them in to two when the width is less.

Or you could write media Query to make it behave differently on different screen sizes

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: unfortunately you're hung up on the numbers I gave in my example.. I have somewhere between 3 and 15 items, and there is room for 7-8 depending on how big they are. I'd like to have a design that equally distributes the items between 2 rows.

Comment: Why not write a script that could measure the length of the `nav` div and sum up the width of each li and divide them into 2 and display the  li accordingly

Comment: that's what I just posted as an option.. I could do it PHP side (with a new UL), but that doesn't address some one making the window narrow.. cause then I'd have full row, single item full row, single item.

Comment: can I script the CSS some how?

Comment: Use jQuery.Check out the `.css()` method, that should get you started.
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: hmm.. that's going to be a bear.. because i have to attach it to the resize event.... ugg.. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: yeah why not call that function on the resize event , so that it fires up every time you resize . jQuery has a resize() method too to do this exactly ..check it out .

Answer (score 0):

Pawan is on the right track.  It would also be helpful to set a min-width on the UL if you want to keep a certain number of LIs on the top row as a minimum.  This can override the div width if you leave overflow at default.

```
ul li { 
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 100px;
```

}

ul { min-width: 300px; }

body { width: 200px; }

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/netsentry/VJA4E/23/)

Comment: That's still doesn't quite address my issue. I'm trying to balance 2 rows, not ensure a certain number on the top row.. I'll update the question with more detail.